# alternating series test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I must determine if this series converges (using specifically the alternating series test) $$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+4}.$$

I know the necessary and sufficient conditions are:
The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges if $a_{(n+1)} \leq a_n$ (or if $f'(x) < 0$) and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0.$

So first I tried to show the derivative, $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+4}) < 0$ and after a bunch of algebra got $\displaystyle\frac{2-x}{\sqrt{x^5} + \sqrt{x^3} + 16 \sqrt{x}} < 0$, but I don't know how to demonstrate if that's really true for all $x \geq 1$.

Next I tried to show $a_{n+1} \leq a_n\  \forall \ n \geq 1$, or 
$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{4(n+1)^2 + 1} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4n^2+1}. \ $ After cross multiplying and some rearranging I get $(4n^2 + 1)\sqrt{n+1} \leq 4n^{\frac{5}{2}} + 8n^\frac{3}{2} + 2\sqrt{n}$, and I don't know how to tell if that's true for all $n \geq 1$.

So I'm stumped.  I know there are other tests.  But this is in the alternating series section so either the alternating series test can show it is convergent, or if not then I know it's divergent.
But the answer in the back of the book says it's convergent.  I just don't know how to prove it.

Any suggestions?

n.b.  The original series goes from $n=4\to\infty$ but I don't know if the 4 is a typo or is intended.

Comment: The condition $a_{(n+1)}\le a_n$ isn't necessary; in fact no condition that depends on finitely many elements of a sequence can be necessary for its convergence, since convergence is invariant under an arbitrary change of finitely many elements.

Comment: On the assumption that your calculation of the derivative is correct (I haven't checked it), what can you say about the sign of the numerator and denominator? Note also that the sum of the first few elements of the series is always finite, so it is possible to apply the alternating series test from some point onwards.

Comment: @Mark Bennet

Assuming the derivative is correct, all I can say is for $n > 2$ the numerator will be negative, and for all $n \geq 1$ the denominator will be positive.  Thus after the first two terms the derivative will be less than zero. But my textbook doesn't say $f'(x) < 0$ for only some $x$.  It says less than zero for all $x$.  

So I still don't see how to demonstrate convergence with the alternating series test.

Comment: Joriki, for an alternating series to be convergent, the stated condition is needed. Ultimately every next term must be less than its immediate predecessor. This is one of the conditions for an alternating series to be convergent. The other one is that the infinite term must go to zero, which it does here.

Comment: Suppose $\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}a_n$ converges $(=Z$ say $)$. Then set $a_1=A, a_2=B, a_3=C$ where $A,B,C$ are any numbers at all. The sum from 1 to infinity is then convergent, and converges to $Z+A+B+C$. Many of the tests of convergence work if they are eventually true (for all $n \gt N$ for some suitable $N$) - in terms of joriki's comment, choose $N$ so that the finite number of exceptions fall in the first $N$ terms. The original proof may be in terms of a strictly alternating series, but the test is readily made more versatile and useful by this simple observation.

Answer (score 3):

Your test of whether $a_n \gt a_{n+1}$ looks odd. Since $a_n, a_{n+1} \gt 0$, you can test whether $a_n^2\gt a_{n+1}^2$ and this comes out as $$\frac{n}{(n+4)^2}\gt \frac {n+1}{(n+5)^2}$$

It is then simple to check (clear fractions, since you are multiplying by positive numbers) that this is true for $n \ge 4$, but not for $n=3$ - which may be why the series starts at $n=4$ in the original question from which yours is derived. Note that adding the extra terms does not affect the convergence of the series.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions for an alternating series to be convergent.
1) For some particular n, the corresponding graph must be declining and by using the derivative, this is easy to verify.
2) The infinite term must go towards zero, which it does.

If you remove the (-1) part, the series will diverge, hence your series is Conditionally Convergent. (Rearranging the terms affect the sum)
Source: Stewart Calculus Chapter 11, section 5